# Active Admin pagination

Tags: pagination, activeadmin

Active Admin's pagination on index pages is great, but we are trying to allow the user to type in the desired page number (in addition to the clickable page buttons).

Their desire is to have a prompt like "Enter Page Number:" and an input box where they can type in the desired page number.

Anyone done this already, or have ideas on how to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom sidebar section like this:

```
sidebar :jump_to_page do
  input :page_number
  input type: :submit
end
```

Then add this to you active_admin.js.coffee file:

```
$ ->
  $("#page_number_submit").on 'click', (e) ->
    page_number = $("#page_number").val()

    if window.location.search.indexOf("page=") > 0
      window.location.search = window.location.search.replace(/page=\d*/, "page=#{page_number}")
    else if window.location.search.indexOf("?") == 0
      window.location.search = window.location.search + "&page=#{page_number}"
    else
      window.location.search = "page=#{page_number}"
```